# How to convert c code to matlab

Tags: c, matlab

I have a c code about 1200 lines long and i want to convert it into matlab. is there any software or website where i can do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could also call the C code from Matlab, which might be easier and the program will certainly run faster. if this is an option for you, check out the Matlab documentation for creating mex-files.

Comment: If you are chewing on large chuncks of data, this is probably the best option.  Unless you can use all built in Matlab vector functions, converting C to Matlab is going to result in orders of magnatude slower code.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of (programming language translation is a harder tasks that you might think). But Matlab syntax should be friendly enough to a C programmer.